# Netflix API play callback

Tags: api, callback, netflix

Does Netflix API have a function for callback now playing video? In other words, is there any way to get information - title, ratings, etc.- of the clip that I am currently watching as real time basis? I has been looking for it, but I cannot find one. I found callback for the instant que. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, that information is not accessible via the API. The API only exposes:

- If the title is in the instant watch queue (In Instant Queue)
- If not in the instant queue, the appropriate action either to add the title to that queue (Add) or play the title (Play)

**References**

- [Netflix REST API Reference: Title States](http://developer.netflix.com/docs/REST_API_Reference#0_96793)
- [Netflix API Feature Requests: Has a title been rented/watched](http://developer.netflix.com/forum/read/124212)
- [Queued: API Challenges](http://www.sitepen.com/blog/2009/03/26/queued-api-challenges/)
- [Netflix JavaScript API](http://developer.netflix.com/docs/JavaScript_APIs)
- [Working with the Netflix API in PHP](http://www.hirahim.com/blog/2010/04/14/working-with-the-netflix-api-in-php/)
- [Netflix API Perl Binding](http://search.cpan.org/dist/WWW-Netflix-API/lib/WWW/Netflix/API.pm)
- [Unraveling the Netflix API - Part I](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/42037/Unraveling-the-Netflix-API-Part-I-Netflix-API-Basi)
- [Unraveling the Netflix API - Part II](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/42088/Unraveling-the-Netflix-API-Part-II-Accessing-the-N)
- [Unraveling the Netflix API - Part III](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/42115/Unraveling-the-Netflix-API-Part-III-Accessing-Subs)
- [Unraveling the Netflix API - Part IV](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/42122/Unraveling-the-Netflix-API-Part-IV-Managing-User-A)